# if Thread.sleep is static, how does individual thread knows it is put to sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I am a bit confused with `Thread.sleep()` method. if `Thread.sleep()` is a static method, how does two threads know which is put to sleep. For example, in the code below, I have two three `Threads`
`main`, `t` and `t1`. I call `Thread.sleep()` always. Not `t.sleep()`. Does it mean Thread.sleep() puts the current Thread to sleep? That means a Thread instance puts to sleep by itself by calling the static method. what if t1 wants to put `t` to sleep. that shouldn't be possible correct?

```
public class ThreadInterrupt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("Starting.");

        Thread t  = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random ran = new Random();

                for (int i = 0; i < 1E8; i++) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("we have been interrupted");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                         //some stuff
                 }
        });    
        t.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(500);
        t.interrupt();
        t.join();

        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does it mean Thread.sleep() puts the current Thread to sleep?

Yes.  Only the current thread can do that.

> What if t1 wants to put t to sleep. that shouldn't be possible correct?

Right.  You can set a `volatile boolean` flag that will cause another thread to call `Thread.sleep(...)` but another thread can't cause a thread to sleep.

```
 volatile boolean shouldSleep = false;
 ...
 // check this flag that might be set by another thread to see if I should sleep
 if (shouldSleep) {
     Thread.sleep(...);
 }
```

Comment: I think so @SotiriosDelimanolis.  Depends on the situation.  I've got a lot of my own timer loops that need it of course.  Sometimes I'm polling some service that needs to be in a sleep loop.  Sometimes I way to be extra responsive without spinning so I add a little sleep.  Depends on the situation.

Comment: how will the boolean flag work, do you mean `t` sets the boolean flag of `t1`? but each thread will have its own scope correct?

Comment: Right @user1988876.  The `shouldSleep` should be within `t`'s class or something.

Comment: each thread gets its own stack; how will the boolean flag of t1 available outside that stack to thread t? I mean is it really possible to set a boolean flag of t1 from t?

Comment: It is @user1988876.  You would say `t1.shouldSleep = true;`.  It is `volatile` so the update will be seen by `t1`.  See this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: so shouldSleep must be a Boolean Object that is stored on heap?

Comment: `shouldSleep` should be a `volatile` field (`boolean` is fine) and should be a field on the `t1` `Runnable` object, yes.

Comment: @Gray: I have tried something similar to what you suggested in comments for changing boolean flags in threads. I have an issue which I have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180458/how-to-set-boolean-flag-of-thread-1-from-thread-2-in-java-multithreading  can you kindly look at it when you find time.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can find the current thread from `Thread.currentThread()`. The current thread only can put itself to sleep.